# how can I find the html element with C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, htmlcontrols

I have this line in my `.aspx`  code:

```
 <div id="view" class="g2" runat="server">
 </div>
```

but when I want to find this element in C#(`aspx.cs`) and send data for it, C# cant find it this way:

```
view.Controls.Add(item);
```

*item is a html element that I made through this code:

```
for(int i=0; i<foods.Count; i++)
{
    HtmlGenericControl item = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    item.Attributes["class"] = "items";
    item.Style["border_bottom"] = "3px solid aqua";

    HtmlImage img = new HtmlImage();
    img.Src = foods[i].picGet();

    HtmlGenericControl mask = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    item.Attributes["class"] = "mask";

    HtmlGenericControl h2 = new HtmlGenericControl("h2");
    item.InnerHtml = foods[i].fnameGet();

    HtmlGenericControl price = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
    item.Attributes["class"] = "price";
    item.InnerHtml = foods[i].priceGet().ToString() + "ریال";

    HtmlGenericControl desc = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
    item.InnerHtml = foods[i].describeGet();

    mask.Controls.Add(h2);
    mask.Controls.Add(price);
    mask.Controls.Add(desc);

    item.Controls.Add(img);
    item.Controls.Add(mask);

    view.Control.Add(item);
}
```

- I have written the namespace `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls`
- I saw a course that did the same thing and was successful
- the error is that even my visual studio cant find the `view` that i used in the last line of the for loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# - reading HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709378/c-sharp-reading-html)

Comment: What exactly is the error you get? Note that you did write `view.Control` instead of `view.Controls` (plural)

Comment: code review: you set `item.InnerHtml` a lot. I think you mean the control you just created instead of "item"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Control.FindControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol) to search control with the specified `id` parameter as follow:

```
Control view = FindControl("view");
//Then add your item to div
view.Controls.Add(item);
```